# Debian - Unable to locate package php7.0

Tags: php, linux, laravel, debian

I'm now using PHP 5.4 on my Debian 7 Wheezy server. For the newest Laravel version I have to update to PHP 7.0.

So I followed a small tutorial on how to update my PHP version. I have to use a PPA because the PHP7.0 isn't officialy released yet.

I did the following steps:

Adding the PPA

`add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

Updating all the packages:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Installing the package

```
apt-get install php7.0
```

But now I get the following error:

```
Unable to locate package php7.0
Couldn't find any package by regex: 'php7.0'
```

I have no idea what goes wrong and I've spend some hours trying solutions I found on internet but nothing works.

Does someone know a solution or an alternative to install PHP 7 on Debian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a ppa for Ubuntu, therefore it may be not be compatitble with Debian as these packages are built for specific Ubuntu's version.

You can view list of available packages inside this ppa herE
https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php

As you can see, there's no php7.0 package build for debian, it's just Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't understood that. I now follow this guide: https://github.com/kasparsd/php-7-debian. Php seems to be installed but it's not working on my site. Another challenge for me to solve :)